# GridView.DataSource is null during PostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datasource, postback

i want to implement a print / download csv from each Gridview in my application. Those get their data by Datasources or directly by

```
gvSample.DataSource = Data;
gvSample.DataBind();
```

Now my first approach was setting a Download-Button into the Footer-Template and handle the Download there

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvSample" runat="server">
 <PagerTemplate>
  <asp:ImageButton  ImageUrl="~/download.gif"  OnClick="dl_Click" runat="server" ID="dl"/>
 </PagerTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

and

```
protected void dl_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    GridView gv = (GridView)this.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent;
    string csv = ToCSV(gv.DataSource); //gv.DataSource is null, DatasourceID aswell
    Response.ContentType = "application/csv";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=file.csv");
    Response.Write(csv);
    Response.End();           
}
```

but i cant access the data.

Comment: paste your whole gridview .aspx code

Comment: I've only ever been able to handle this before using jQuery TableTools or RadGrid's custom export methods. DataSource is essentially write only and it will be null on subsequent calls because the data is now bound. You could handle this by putting the data in Session or ViewState, I suppose - but in both cases, I'd strongly recommend you don't.

Comment: instead of using string csv = ToCSV(gv.DataSource), try string csv = ToCSV(Data)

Comment: Can I point out that CSV's are not that great a format for transferring data? Instead you should use Open Office XML Spreadsheet/Excel files (if intended for human consumption) or XML/JSON (if intended for use by a computer). Also, a GridView is a UI control. It should not serve as the source of data in your application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`DataSource` in `GridView` is not stored in any persistent way across `Postback` so you have to save it somewhere ([Viewstate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) or [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(v=vs.100).aspx)) or you have to request it again from your data-store (Es your db).

A quick explanation of the 3 methods:

**VievState**: is saved in an hidden field in the page so it is not recommended for large data-set because your page could become many MB. It's advantage is that it is saved in the page so it does not expire

```
ViewState["Data"] = GetData();
gvSample.DataSource = ViewState["Data"];
gvSample.DataBind();

...

protected void dl_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    string csv = ToCSV(ViewState["Data"]);
    ...   
}
```

**Session**: is saved in the serve memory so you 'quite' don't have size problems but session does not last forever (usually 30minutes) and if a user display that page and click download after an hour than the session will be null

```
Session["Data"] = GetData();
gvSample.DataSource = Session["Data"];
gvSample.DataBind();

...

protected void dl_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    string csv = ToCSV(Session["Data"]);
    ...   
}
```

**Request from data-store** you request the data from the db so another round trip is done and data could be different respect what the user are seeing

```
gvSample.DataSource = GetData();
gvSample.DataBind();

...

protected void dl_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    string csv = ToCSV(GetData());
    ...   
}
```

Just a suggestion:

you can access simpler the grid using directly `gvSample` in this way it will be not broken if you cange your html...:

```
protected void dl_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    //GridView gv = (GridView)this.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent;
    //string csv = ToCSV(gv.DataSource); //gv.DataSource is null, DatasourceID aswell
    string csv = ToCSV(gvSample.DataSource);
    ...   
}
```

Comment: @fubo yes I forget that in gridview datasource is not stored in viestate automatically (as in other asp.net controls). you have to save it somewhere or request again from your datastore.. Check my updated answer

Answer (score 5):

You could save your data in `ViewState` (NOT RECCOMENDED FOR LARGE DATASETS!!!), roughly

```
gvSample.DataSource = Data;
ViewState["Data"] = Data;
gvSample.DataBind();
```

---

```
protected void dl_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    var ds = (ProperDataType)ViewState["Data"]; // TODO: check for nulls
    string csv = ToCSV(ds); //gv.DataSource is null, DatasourceID aswell
    Response.ContentType = "application/csv";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=file.csv");
    Response.Write(csv);
    Response.End();           
}
```

Also, you could rebuild your data based on the gridview, something like

```
var ds = new ProperDataSource();
foreach(GridViewRow row in gvSample.Rows)
{
    dRow data = new dRow();
    foreach(TableCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        ds.Add("column1", cell.Text);
    }
    ds.Add(dRow);
}
string csv = ToCSV(ds); //gv.DataSource is null, DatasourceID aswell
        Response.ContentType = "application/csv";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=file.csv");
        Response.Write(csv);
        Response.End();
```

of course you have to fit this snippet to your specific data structure... but that's the general idea.

GridViews don't save it's original datasource, you have to either save it elsewhere or rebuild it on demand

Answer (score 2):

> You Can't Access it gv.DataSource as You Coded

Try to Use `Session` or `ViewStates`  and Save `DataTable`

```
gvSample.DataSource = Data;
gvSample.DataBind();
Session["MyTable"]=Data;
```

Convert `Session` into `DataTable` and pass to Method

```
protected void dl_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    if(Session["MyTable"]==null)
{

    string csv = ToCSV(DataTable(Session["MyTable"]) );  
    Response.ContentType = "application/csv";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=file.csv");
    Response.Write(csv);
    Response.End();    

}       
}
```