# Create new page as control and show in a popup window

Tags: c#, asp.net

Essentially, what I want to do is this:

```
protected void Imgexport_Click(object sender, System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    //get the download page as an object (requires complex parameter)
    GenericExcelDownloader Ged = new GenericExcelDownloader(gvEquipmentRuntime, "Projected Maintenance Report.xls");

    //get the response stream from the download page
    StringWriter sWriter = new StringWriter();

    HtmlTextWriter hTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sWriter);
    Ged.RenderControl(hTextWriter);

    //????
    //Profit?
    //WHAT DO?
}
```

The control I called contains code during page load which essentially ends like so:  (there are other modifications made to the grid, which is added to the Div referenced as "Download" below)

```
Response.ClearContent();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
Response.Charset = "";
Response.ContentType = "application/excel";

StringWriter sWriter = new StringWriter();

HtmlTextWriter hTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sWriter);

Download.RenderControl(hTextWriter);//this is a Div on the page which contains the visible portion of the page control

Response.Output.Write(sWriter.ToString());
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

The end goal is that on the click of the button, the div on the other page containing a modified version of the grid view passed in as an initial parameter in the click event, is downloaded on the client machine.

Where I'm stuck, is that I dont know how to get the ASPX Page in my code behind which I have as an object, into the front end.  I dont even know for sure if my initial attempt is the correct starting place.  Because of the complex parameter and its size I dont want to solely rely on a `window.open` with string parameters and/or a session variable...

**UPDATE: *WORKAROUND***

I found a method which will accomplish my goal, although the original question hasn't actually been answered

By making use of `Server.Execute()` I was able to directly run the sub-page.  It also gives me access to the `Page.PreviousPage` property, which is an object level reference to the calling page, which contains the complex object I needed.  I then can back reference the page to get this object directly on the sub-page.  The code looks something like this

```
protected void Imgexport_Click(object sender, System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    Server.Execute("GenericExcelDownloader.aspx?Report=Projected%20Maintenance%20Report%2Exls", true);            
}
```

and on the other side

```
ReportName = Request.QueryString["Report"];
if (PreviousPage != null && PreviousPage is iReportPage)
    ReportGrid = ((iReportPage)PreviousPage).ReportView;
```

This now allows the page to process directly, and have it's response handled so that it will download the grid the way I need it to.

*KNOWN ISSUE:*

> DataSource in GridView is not stored in any persistent way across Postback so you have to save it somewhere (Viewstate or Session) or you have to request it again from your data-store (Es your db). [Gridview Datasource is Null During Postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26931784/gridview-datasource-is-null-during-postback)

I ended up tabling this entire experiment shortly after I got it working because of that.  I wanted to avoid stashing all the data in memory, *And* avoid having to re-generate the grid during the post back.  Apparently this is impossible, so I need to accomplish this in a slightly more direct manner.

I'm still quite interested in the answer to the original question though, I can imagine multiple uses for this.